4Read file from executable spring boot jar on Java 17
I have a jar with the following structure on my jar:

I am trying to read the file under custom/file.txt but it's throwing me an error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/Users/josh/github/gov-aus-api/app/target/gov-aus-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/custom/file.txt

My code is very simple:
@Component("LoaderImpl")
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class LoaderImpl {
 
     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
         FileReader in = null;
         try {
             URL url = getClass().getResource("/custom/file.txt");
             File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(url);
            // File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:custom/file.txt");
            // Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("custom/file.txt");
            // File file = resource.getFile();
             in = new FileReader(file);

         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Cant load file");
         } 
     }
}

Same code working running on IntelliJ but what's not working when try to run .jar file? How can I read it from .jar and inside my Intellij?
Usinig Java 17 and Spring 2.7.x
edit:
I have changed my code to:
@Component("LoaderImpl")
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class LoaderImpl {

    @Value("classpath:custom/file.txt")
    private Resource resource;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cant load file");
        }
    }
}

my pom.xml is simple:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gov.aus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gov-aus-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gov-aus-api</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Now I can fill the Reader but why ResourceUtils or ResourceLoader not works on init() method?

Check if the file exists in jar. Jar is just zip file, you can rename it and open it.

It exists, I already checked that.

Maybe try classpath:/custom/file.txt

Already tried with a dash

Hehe @talex you beat me to it with that suggestion. Did it work placplacboom?

No. I have all files when I check BOOT-INF/classes/custom/file.txt

Could be a Spring quirk. Not quite sure how it does its classloading

if your file is indeed INSIDE of your src/main/resources then the ResourceUtils.getFile("custom/file.txt") would have found it. I think you made a typo somethere and since you have obfuscated all the details such as the actual names and file paths, we can't see it here

I have updated the question, the file is there, there is no typo

/custom/file.txt is an absolute path, you need to use custom/file.txt

Check the print and my code. There is nothing obfuscated

The custom folder needs to be in the root folder and not beneath BOOT-INF

How I do that? @triplem

Via your pom.xml and/ or gradle buildfile

String textFile = new String(getClass().getResource("/custom/file.txt").openStream().readAllBytes()); says what?

NullPointer on openStream! I think its something related to Spring!

As I said, unfortunately I don't know how its classloaders work, but when you get the resource, I'm guessing my code will fulfill your use case in its one line

Please post your resource copy block from your pom.xml, then we can try to help you further.

@triplem done! I make it working but not sure why dont work with other resources

So does that code I posted now work?

Method getFile(String) searches the file system. However, you say that the file – file.txt – is in the JAR file. Hence method getFile(String) is not appropriate.
You can use method getResource as in...
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("/custom/file.txt"); // Note leading slash
ResourceUtils.getFile(url.toURI());

You wrote (in your question):

Same code working running on IntelliJ but what's not working when try to run .jar file

That's because when you run it from IntelliJ, it is using the file system (and not the JAR).

Same problem. It works on IntelliJ but it didn't work on .jar file. I extracted all stuff from .jar and the creepy file is overthere

@placplacboom What is the context for this line of your code: File myFile = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:custom/file.txt"); Is it a static method? Is it an instance method? Or is myFile a class variable?

I have updated the question with entire code and entire error message, @Abra

did you check my update?
